# Keyboard shortcut (hotkey) for switching keyboard layout on iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth, shortcut

I use iPad mini 4 (iOS 10.1.1) with a Logitech bluetooth keyboard (k380). I often need to switch the keyboard layout because I use more than one language in my writings.

Currently I have to turn off the keyboard and click on the "world" icon on the screen keyboard to change its layout. Then turn on the keyboard. Not practical.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for switching keyboard layout on iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Did you know that answers on SE must be at least 30 characters?

Comment: Control + Space as well.

Comment: @TomGewecke Can you confirm this on iOS 10?

Comment: Yes, works fine for me.  Same as for MacOS.

Comment: why it doesn't work for me?